# Persist an object to either local file system or to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I need a method which persists an object (model) to either local file system or to an S3 bucket. The destination is determined by the environment variable `MODELS_DIR`. I have two versions where the first is a little longer and I am rather confident about its correctness. The second version is shorter, but I am worried that not using the `with` statement is actually wrong.

```
def persist_model(model, model_name):
    """ VERSION 1
    Persist `model` under the name `model_name` to the environment variable
    `MODELS_DIR` (having a trailing '/').
    """
    MODELS_DIR = os.getenv('MODELS_DIR')

    if MODELS_DIR.startswith('s3://'):
        s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
        with s3.open(MODELS_DIR[5:] + model_name, 'wb') as f:
            joblib.dump(model, f)
    else:
        with open(MODELS_DIR + model_name, 'wb') as f:
            joblib.dump(model, f)
```

and:

```
def persist_model(model, model_name):
    """VERSION 2
    Persist `model` under the name `model_name` to the environment variable
    `MODELS_DIR` (having a trailing '/').
    """
    MODELS_DIR = os.getenv('MODELS_DIR')

    if MODELS_DIR.startswith('s3://'):
        s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
        f = s3.open(MODELS_DIR[5:] + model_name, 'wb')
    else:
        f = open(MODELS_DIR + model_name, 'wb')

    joblib.dump(model, f)
```

My question is whether the second version is safe to use?

Answer (score 3):

Yes an no... normally you would need to close the file after you wrote (dumped) your content in it.
When you use the ***with*** statement, Python will take care for that. If you skip the with, you need to use ***f.close()*** or ***s.close()***.

Also, to be sure that the file gets closed even in case of an error, you would need to use the try-finally construct. Therefore the second version, when used correctly, would become way longer than the first one.

In case you would like to avoid the code duplication, I would propose the use of a function selector:

```
 def persist_model(model, model_name):

     def get_file_opener(path):
        if path.startswith('s3://'):
            return s3fs.S3FileSystem().open
        else 
            return open

     full_path = os.getenv('MODELS_DIR')
     with get_file_opener(fullpath)(fullpath[5:] + model_name, 'wb') as f:
        joblib.dump(model, f)
```